# MySQL: Inserting records in one table reading from another, without locking

Tags: mysql, performance, locking

I'm trying to do esentially this:

```
INSERT INTO stuff_to_archive
  SELECT a.id FROM stuff a INNER JOIN items b ON a.b_id = b.id AND (other conditions on b)
```

Basically, "stuff" grows too big, and I want to archive old records nightly. Stuff_to_archive has the IDs of records to archive, which I later use as an auxiliary to make sure i'm creating and deleting the same records. I'm trying to do this without locking either "stuff" or "items", so the rest of my site can keep working.

I'm joining into items, because items has information on which "stuff" records I can archive. Now, all records matched by this query (in both tables) are never being written to. Both tables have new records added all the time, and "items" has records updated, but not the records that i'm matching (because those are old and not touched anymore)

Stuff and Items are InnoDB. Stuff_to_archive is MEMORY.

Is there any way to run that query without blocking other reads/writes on stuff and items?
I've tried

```
set SESSION transaction isolation level READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

But that still seems to block everything.

This INSERT in creating about 2 Million records into the stuff_to_archive table.

Is there any way to make this INSERT without blocking other queries?

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that great with InnoDB locks, but there is a global setting and a session setting for isolation levels in InnoDB, you can check them both from the MySQL terminal:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation, @@tx_isolation;
```

Try setting the global transaction level maybe:

```
SET GLOBAL transaction isolation level READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

You could also try disabling `autocommit` for all new connections and see if that makes a difference

```
SET GLOBAL init_connect='SET autocommit=0';
```